# Splitting dates

Tags: php, date, datetime

```
$one = array('start' => '2012-10-12', 'stop' => '2012-11-04', 'over' => false);
$two = array('start' => '2012-10-29', 'stop' => '2012-11-14', 'over' => true);
$three = array('start' => '2012-11-12', 'stop' => '2012-12-07', 'over' => false);

$array = array($one, $two, $three);
```

this show me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-12
            [stop] => 2012-11-04
            [over] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-29
            [stop] => 2012-11-14
            [over] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-11-12
            [stop] => 2012-12-07
            [over] => 
        )

)
```

I would like make function for splitting these dates.
If in array is **over = true** then this date should split other dates.

For this example this should return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array                  //this is changed
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-12
            [stop] => 2012-10-28
            [over] => 
        )

    [1] => Array                   //this is ok
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-29
            [stop] => 2012-11-14
            [over] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array                  //this is changed
        (
            [start] => 2012-11-15
            [stop] => 2012-12-07
            [over] => 
        )

)
```

And second example:

```
$one = array('start' => '2012-10-12', 'stop' => '2012-12-04', 'over' => false);
$two = array('start' => '2012-10-29', 'stop' => '2012-11-14', 'over' => true);


$second = array($one, $two);
```

this return me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-12
            [stop] => 2012-12-04
            [over] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-29
            [stop] => 2012-11-14
            [over] => 1
        )

)
```

and i would like receive:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array                  //this is changed - old [0] date
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-12
            [stop] => 2012-10-28
            [over] => 
        )

    [1] => Array                  //this is ok
        (
            [start] => 2012-10-29
            [stop] => 2012-11-14
            [over] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array                  //this is new - from old [0] date - next part
        (
            [start] => 2012-11-15
            [stop] => 2012-12-04
            [over] => 
        )
)
```

- http://codepad.org/tqtEYstB
- http://codepad.org/6fYkYVQ8

How can I do it with PHP?

Comment: Basically, if `$a[i+1]['over'] == true`, then `$a[i]['stop'] = $a[i+1]['start'] minus 1 day`?

Comment: yes, but how can i make for this simply function?

Comment: I'd loop over the arrays, check if `over` is true, and do the date arithmetic. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
   if(isset($arr[$key+1]) && $arr[$key+1]['over'] == true)
       $arr[$key]['stop'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr[$key+1]['start'] .' -1 day'));
  if(isset($arr[$key-1]) && $arr[$key-1]['over'] == true)
       $arr[$key]['start'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr[$key-1]['stop'] .' +1 day'));
}
```

you can find the [code](http://codepad.org/ErNXcdCH) here.

**Update:**

```
 $arr1 = $arr;
 foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
   if(isset($arr[$key+1]) && $arr[$key+1]['over'] == true)
   {
       $arr[$key]['stop'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr[$key+1]['start'] .' -1 day'));
       $arr[$key]['over'] = true;
   }
   if(isset($arr[$key-1]) && $arr[$key-1]['over'] == true)
   {
       $arr[$key]['start'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arr[$key-1]['stop'] .' +1 day'));
       $arr[$key]['over'] = true;
   }
 }

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val)
{
   $arr[$key]['over'] = $arr1[$key]['over'];
}
```

your **updated** [code](http://codepad.org/WLmdFvQN) here.

Comment: thanks, this working ok, but in second example i must add last part date from date [0]

Comment: sorry - if i change and add over=>true for first element and remove from second element this not working for third element

Comment: can you please briefly explain your second example?

Comment: then you need to set over = true if the value is changed. right?

Comment: no, in example is [0] = false, [1] = true, [2] = false. now i would like check this for new example - [0] = true, [1] = false, [2] = false

Comment: thanks, but is bad for [0] = false, [1] = false and [2] = true ;) http://codepad.org/U4j4r6ri

Comment: what is the expected result for that case?

Comment: you should elaborate everything the question itself.